# GUI application runs in Spyder and cmd but not as a standalone .exe

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am building a GUI application for plotting data. The program runs fine in Spyder and through command prompt, but after compiling it I noticed that the GUI opens up, accepts inputs but does not plot when I hit the "Plot" button. Instead it closes down unexpectedly. I've now simplified the code to the bare minimum that I think I need to do what I want. Please see the code below.
I am using cx_Freeze to create my executable program. The code for the setup file is also included below. 
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class DataPlotter:
    def __init__(self,master):   

        master.geometry('300x100+200+100')
        master.title('Data Plotter')
        master.resizable(False,False)

        def PlotFigure(self,fig):
            self.Window = tk.Toplevel(master)                    
            self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self.Window)
            self.canvas.show()
            self.frametool = tk.Frame(self.Window)
            self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas,self.frametool)
            self.toolbar.update()
            self.frametool.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH)
            self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
            self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        def Run(self): #       
            try:
                app = Plotter(x=range(0,10), y=range(0,10))
                PlotFigure(self,app.plotting())
            except Exception as ex:
                messagebox.showinfo('Caught Error','Exception caught: ' + str(ex))
        ttk.Button(master, text='Plot', command=lambda:Run(self)).pack(anchor='center') 

class Plotter(object):
    def __init__(self, x=None, y=None):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def plotting(self):
        fig = Figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(self.x, self.y, 'o-')
        return fig

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.grab_set()
    root.focus()
    DataPlotter(root)    
    root.mainloop()
if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Setup file below:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\tcl\tk8.6'

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

executables = [Executable('Data_Plotter.py', base=base)]

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os","tkinter","numpy","matplotlib"]}

setup(
    name = "Data_Plotter",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    version = "1.0",
    description = "This program plots data and displays the graph in a new window",
    executables = executables
)
```

Comment: What happens if you run you `.exe` from command line ? Do you get any error message that would help investigating ?

Comment: Perhaps try to shrink your code to have a better idea of what causes the problem. Like creating a [mcve].